# How to delete the last letter from EditText with button?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-button

I have to buttons that writes A and B to an edittext. If there is something in the edittext how can I delete the last letters with the "Del" button ?

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonb"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/buttona"
android:text="@string/buttonb"
android:textSize="50sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttona"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text="@string/buttona"
android:textSize="50sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttondel"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text="@string/buttondel"
android:textSize="50sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:ems="58"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:inputType="text" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my java:

```
package com.koostamas.keyboard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button buttona, buttondel;
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

addListenerOnButton();
}


   public void addListenerOnButton() {

buttona = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttona);
buttona.setOnClickListener(this);

buttondel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonb);
buttondel.setOnClickListener(this);


   }

public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttona : 
        Button buttona = (Button)v;
    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString()+buttona.getText().toString());
        break;
    case R.id.buttondel :
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        editText.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
        break;



}

}


}
```

How can I do it? Thanks inn advance.

Comment: Do not ask the same questions multiple times.  Especially not in the same day.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get an answer I could use for the former question.

Comment: You got several answers, many of which were right.  The answers here are the exact same.

Comment: ok but I'm not an expert on android and I didn't know how to use them.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can retrieve the text of `EditText` and then get the `sub-string` of that text and set again that text to `EditText` as below...

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
editText.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
```

You can also use following procedure....it will be more efficient.

```
int length = editText.getText().length();
if (length > 0) {
    editText.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
}
```

You should use `switch-case` as below...and handle your `nuttondel` onclick() as follows...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button buttona, buttonb;
    Button buttonDel;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }


   public void addListenerOnButton() {

    buttona = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttona);
    buttona.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonb);
    buttonb.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondel);
    buttonDel.setOnClickListener(this);


   }

    public void onClick(View v) {

       switch(v.getId()) {

          case R.id.buttona:
                      editText.setText(editText.getText().toString()+buttona.getText().toString());
              break;

          case R.id.buttonb:
                      editText.setText(editText.getText().toString()+buttonb.getText().toString());
              break;

          case R.id.buttondel:

              int length = editText.getText().length();
              if (length > 0) {
                  editText.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
              }
              break;
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the str variable in the 3rd line?

Comment: @user2923589...see my updated answer...I think this answer will help you lot.

Comment: An efficient way would be `int length = editText.getText().length();if (length > 0) {editText.getText().delete(length - 1, length);}`

Comment: @GopalRao...thanks for your concern. In have updated my answer. I wouldn't know that.

Comment: what if my cursor is at center and want to remove center charactor

Comment: i use the efficient way just because the cursor is placed in the correct position

Answer (score 6):

Using substring() method , you can do it,

```
String str = myEditText.getText().toString();
str = str.substring ( 0, str.length() - 1 );
// Now set this Text to your edit text
myEditText.setText ( str );
```

you need to write above lines in onClick() method.

Comment: But where should I put it? Could you write it into the code?  Thanks.

Comment: Please tell me, which is your del button  ?

Comment: Good, you have done right thing.

Comment: That would cause an error when the `EditText` is empty. Add `if(str.length() > 0) { ... }` to catch this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
str=edittext.gettext+"";
str.length();
```

then for loop 
or `str1 = str.substring ( 0, str.length() - 1 );`

Comment: But where should I put it? Could you write it into the code? Thanks.

Comment: on button click u want na? then put it on button click event... this will remove last character

Comment: I can't do it. It does nothing.

Comment: then again settext(str1)